# Use overload function in httpGet with route attribute

Tags: c#, api, http-get

I have an api web service,
I want to use overload functions option in c#, I have 2 methods with the same name and the routes get duplicate Route

```
[Route("getConfigVal")]
    [HttpGet]
    public long getConfigVal(int key, double sResult)
    {
        try
        {
            return _service.getConfigVal(key, ref sResult);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.HResult;
        }

    }

    [Route("getConfigVal")]
    [HttpGet]
    public long getConfigVal( int key, DateTime sResult)
    {
        try
        {
            return _service.getConfigVal(key, ref sResult);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.HResult;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly specify the routes? The syntax `getConfigVal/{id:int}/...`,where ... Is the overload, ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: This is the very definition of a duplicate route. What is your question?